# Charter flights to India

Tags: india, covid-19, charter

India is allowing tourists to enter from the middle of October, but only on charter flights.

What I think of as a charter flight is the kind of flight you get on if you are on a package tour... i.e. it's chartered by the tour operator and everyone on it has booked a travel + accommodation package with that operator / its partners.

Then again, if you book a private jet to take you wherever you're going, that's also a "charter flight".

I am wondering:

- What counts as a charter flight for the purposes of the Indian rules?
- Is there any easy way to find these flights?

I am specifically looking for a flight departing from Dubai but when I search "package tour india dubai" I get packages that use scheduled flights, and when I search for charter flights I get private jets.

Comment: You don’t have to be on a package tour to book a charter flight.

Comment: @Traveller Well yes, if you know who chartered it and if they will let you... but how do you find that out?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.